# HTTPS configuration w/ Apache2 and Docker

Tags: apache, docker, ssl, https, docker-compose

trying to enable HTTPS on a dockerized web application.

The host server uses a non-dockerized installation of Apache2 as a webserver.

It seems like to enable HTTPS for the app, both the dockerized web-app and the Apache2 webserver must listen on port 443 (?) and this creates a conflict, throwing the following error on docker-compose up:

```
ERROR: for <appname>  Cannot start service 
<appname>: driver failed programming external 
connectivity on endpoint <appname> 
(containerid): Error starting userland 
proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: listen: 
address already in use
```

I have tried having Apache2 listen on port 443, exposing another port in docker-compose file (8000), and mapping this port to 443 in the compose file like so:

```
networks:
  - default
ports:
  - 0.0.0.0:8000:443
```

however the server fails to return a response with this configuration.

I am very new to Docker, Apache2, and systems in general, and am am sure there is a better solution available (for instance, I could simply run Apache2 within a docker container), but how can I make this specific configuration work with HTTPS if at all?

Further, what is the best practice for HTTPS configuration when using Docker and Apache2 in general?

Let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? This is my problem, as well.